# Usage of "regulatory testing" in the mentioned text?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> In industry, decisions to go ahead with animal experiments will be
>   based on an internal scientific discussion and economic evaluation.
>   For the other main area of animal experiments, the so- called
>   **regulatory testing**, it is the legal requirements for testing new substances and devices which provide the reason for using animals.
>   ([Source](http://assets.cambridge.org/97811084/20617/excerpt/9781108420617_excerpt.pdf))

Is "the regulatory testing" an elaboration on "other main area of animal experiment"? Is "regulatory resting" a professional expression, as the "so-called" indicates?

Comment: [The original](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/166245/1) is a kind of question we are trying to discourage. If you don’t understand what something means, don’t simply paste the text and ask what it means. And don’t say, “Googling didn’t help,” either. **Tell us what you Googled or looked up in a dictionary. Tell us what you found when you did that research. Then explain why you still need help to understand the phrase in your question.** It’s not the job of the community to look something up in a dictionary for you, and no one should ask a question as though they expect that it is.

Comment: @J.R. I refined the question.

Comment: regulatory is the adjective for regulations.

Answer (score 1):

*Regulatory testing* is what industries must do to verify that they are in compliance with (government) *regulations* ([Regulatory Compliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulatory_compliance)).  The particular testing for this industry is defined in the paragraph: *"the legal requirements for testing new substances and devices (on animals)"*, typical for things like pharmaceuticals and cosmetics.

Animal testing is only one of many types of *regulatory testing*.  Other examples:

> - EMC testing (testing electromagnetic emissions for use in EM sensitive environments or applications)
> - Product safety testing (testing the product does not pose any unnecessary or unexpected risks to users)
> - Agency compliance certifications / markings (making sure the product adheres to agency regulations and bears appropriate labels, markings, or warnings)
> - Acoustics testing (testing the sound a device makes to verify it doesn't exceed certain restrictions)

and many others.